# How to know if a photo is black or too dark?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image-processing, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerViewController where the user takes a photo. My problem is how to know before uploading the photo to the server if the user is sending a dark photo. I mean a totally or nearly black.

I was researching and I found this:

```
const UInt8 *pixels = CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData);
UInt8 blackThreshold = 10; // or some value close to 0
int bytesPerPixel = 4;
for(int x = 0; x < width1; x++) {
  for(int y = 0; y < height1; y++) {
    int pixelStartIndex = (x + (y * width1)) * bytesPerPixel;
    UInt8 alphaVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex]; // can probably ignore this value
    UInt8 redVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 1];
    UInt8 greenVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 2];
    UInt8 blueVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 3];
    if(redVal < blackThreshold && blueVal < blackThreshold && greenVal < blackThreshold) {
      //This pixel is close to black...do something with it
    }
  }
}
```

However, I don't know how to apply the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Yep that's a fairly simple way of doing it. You could, for example, iterate through and see what percentage of the pixels are pure black (i.e. clipped shadows) or nearly black. Or you could average the pixel colors throughout the whole image and see if it falls below a certain threshold. There are lots of approaches and these two might be a tad simplistic, but I'm not sure if this calls for anything particularly sophisticated. What threshold you want to use is up to you.

Also, while it has little practical impact, if I was going to be picky about the algorithm, I might only perform the "brightness" logic if the `alphaVal` was over a certain threshold, as well, as the color information is meaningless at transparent portions of image. Having said that, real photos rarely have any transparency, so this may be non-issue.

FYI, here is [Apple's code for retrieving the pixel buffer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1509/_index.html). It's an oldie, but a goodie. (If I recall correctly, the only hassle is that the `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst` reference in `CreateARGBBitmapContext` must be cast with `(CGBitmapInfo)`.)

---

By the way, if you're trying to determine the luminance of a particular pixel, one common algorithm is:

```
luminance = 0.2126 * red + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue
```